# Laravel 5.2 $this->dispatch didn't call handle function

Tags: redis, laravel-5, queue

Laravel 5.2 `$this->dispatch` 
didn't call handle function

I use the following controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\SendReminderEmail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Redis;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send a reminder e-mail to a given user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendReminderEmail()
    {
        $this->dispatch(new SendReminderEmail());
    }
}
```

and the job file is

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Redis;
use Mail;
use App\User;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendReminderEmail extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function handle()
    {
      $redis = Redis::connection();
      $redis->set('org', 'Mycompany');
    }
}
```

when i call the controller function and check redis server for org variable i got null value!

How can i call the job function?

Comment: Have you setup the queue properly and have a queue listener or worker running? Remove the ` implements ShouldQueue` on the job class and try running the code without the queue, see if you get the desired result.

Comment: Its working now, Thanks :) .. but what is the problem of implements ShouldQueue

Comment: `ShouldQueue` forces the job to run in the queue instead of executing it synchronously. If you haven't configured the queue then it might cause issues with the job. Use it only when you want to force every job to be queued.

Answer (score 0):

Set QUEUE_DRIVER=sync in the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

locally you can run

```
php artisan queue:work
```

it will run all jobs from the queue